# Как установить модуль android на python?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, установка

Делаю программу для андроидов с веб интерфейсом(использую eel + html/css/js), мне надо было узнать геолокацию пользователя, нашел рабочий код с модулем android. Установить не получилось(использую pip), сама ошибка:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement android (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for android
```

Android устанавливается автоматически с kivy, но kivy я не использую и не собираюсь использовать. Есть ли возможность установить android через pip?

Comment: Судя по ошибке, вы пытались установить несуществующий модуль. Разве есть модуль `android`? Разве `kivy` не генерирует код, совместимый с андроидом, без установки андроида (или его эмулятора)?

Comment: Вот ссылка на вопрос: https://qna.habr.com/q/637307. Там человек показывает код, где импортирует модуль android.

Comment: https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/stable/old_toolchain/android/

Comment: Вы так устанавливали `pip install python-for-android`? https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart/#installation

Comment: Нет, я устанавливал просто так:
 pip install android

Comment: @SmartBeetle так может быть стоит попробовать установить через `pip install python-for-android`? Вам выше дали ссылку на страницу документации модуля, который вы хотите использовать, и там показан именно такой пример.

Comment: Спасибо, если понадобится, то установлю. Видно так его и надо устанавливать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способ уcтановить модуль `android` есть:

```
pip install python-for-android
```

Но я пошел обходным путем: я использую `javascript` (так как работаю с веб интерфейсом) и в `javascript` есть встроенный модуль `navigator`, а в нем функция: `geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, который как раз и решает мою проблему. Спасибо всем, кто мне помог